# Solving of the second-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving differential equation $2yy''=y^2+y'^2$. I guess it necessary to reduce an order. I try to write equation in terms of $y'=u$. I get the first-order equation, and after i let $u=zy$. But then i have trouble with solving. Is that way right or i make mistake?

Comment: It might help to compute $(y^2)''$ and $(y y')'$ and then consider the substitution $f = y^2$ or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Write the equation as $\ds{{y'' \over y} = \half + {y'^{2} \over 2y^{2}}}$. With $\ds{z \equiv \ln\pars{y}}$:

> \begin{align}
> {y'' \over y}&={1 \over y}\,\totald{}{x}\pars{y\,\totald{\ln\pars{y}}{x}}
> =\bracks{\totald{\ln\pars{y}}{x}}^{2} + \totald[2]{\ln\pars{y}}{x}
> = z'^{2} + z''
> \\[3mm]
> {y' \over y} &= \totald{\ln\pars{y}}{x} = z'
> \end{align}

Then,
$$
z'^{2} + z'' = \half + \half\,z'^{2}\quad\imp\quad z''=\half\pars{1 - z'^{2}}
\quad\imp\quad{\dd z' \over 1 - z'^{2}} = \half\,\dd x
$$

> $$
> {\rm arctanh}\pars{z'} = \half\,x + A\,,\qquad A\ \mbox{is a constant}
> $$

$$
z' = \tanh\pars{\half\,x + A}\quad\imp\quad
z=2\ln\pars{\root{B}\cosh\pars{{x \over 2} + A}}\,,
\qquad B\ \mbox{is a constant}
$$

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large y}= \expo{z}
> =\color{#66f}{\large B\cosh^{2}\pars{\half\,x + A}}
> $$